# Problem with passing parameters to rdl report

Tags: parameters, range, rdl

I developed an rdl report which is being called from an ASP application.

The cube that I'm using to extract data contains a time dimintion and in the report I have some parameters passed from ASP to filter the result.

The problem is:
For all the time fields, when I'm using "From" "To" parameters I got invalid results:

Example: in Day field I passed values (FromDay=1,ToDay=2) but the result contains values :

1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2

I feel that the reason that the report treat the parameter as a text parameter.

I searched the internet a lot and I couldn't found anything useful.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance